# Repairing the master boot record of an external HDD that is in RAW format

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partition-recovery

I have an external HDD that has somehow become corrupted and as a result I cannot access any of the files that was on it because it's now in "RAW" format.

However, if I use a data recovery program like EaseUS or MiniTool it is able to find all of the files and I can save a copy of them. The problem with this is that it is unable to retain the folder structure which is a big deal.

How do fix the masterboot record in Windows 10 as I am unable to find the device name using `map` therefore I can't do `bootrec /fixmbr \device\harddiskname`

Any advice?

Comment: The MBR has nothing to do with the folder structure, so I'm not sure why you're trying to fix it.  Regardless of that, from what you've described, the file system lost it's structure; it's gone.  Restore from backup, or recover the files as best you can and restructure their layout yourself.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The drive has a corrupted MBR hence why it's in RAW format, the folder structure is correct it's just all of the tools to recover data of a hard drive pull the files off in sorted folders of filetype. The "lack in folder structure" has nothing to do with the harddrive, rather the software. So yes I do want to fix the mbr